# Problem with colortbl and makecell

Tags: tables, multirow, colortbl, makecell

Here is an simple example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c}
  longer text\\
  \cellcolor{teal}\\
  \cellcolor{teal}\multirowcell{-2}[0ex][r]{short\\short}
%   \cellcolor{teal}\multirow{-2}*{short} % is ok but can't break line or set alignment
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

When the text in the multirowcell is shorter than than the text of the above cell, the cell will not be colored well. `multirow` is ok, but I want to break line inside the cell and set the alignment.

Cauze the code will be generated by python and the width of the column is impossible to be accessed in program nor be setted to a just suitable value, options such as `p`, `w` in `array` or `X` in `tabularx` is not considered.

Comment: there is no reason at all to use multrow here as you can not span any rows of the table as there are no other columns.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I removed other unnecessary columns and rows. Just suppose I must do it in this way. I know the best way is not to write in this way, but I wonder if there is a solution without specifying the width of the column no matter how complicated and unnecessary the solution is. Cause I'm writing a conversion script...

Comment: you can use a nested `\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}` in the entry, but getting multiple lines within a cell is completely unrelated to making that cell span rows or columns.

Comment: It works, thanks you anyway

Comment: please post solutions as answers not by editing the question (even if it's using my comment) otherwise the question-answer format of the site is messed up for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

With use the `w{c}{...}` column type is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}  % it load colortbl
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{w{c}{5em}}
  longer text       \\
\rowcolor{teal}
\makecell{short\\short}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Also is simple with use new `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}  % with tabularray the colortbl is not needed

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{c}
  longer text       \\
  \SetRow{cyan!30}
{short\\short}
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}  

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{row{2}={cyan!30,c}, c}
  longer text       \\
{short\\short}
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

In the both cases the result is the same:

[image]

Comment: The code will be generated by python, so I can not get the width setted correctly. Using nested tarbular is suitable  for me.

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck, in question is not mentioned, that you limited to use of `phynton` ...

Comment: I'm sorry for that... I will modify the question

Comment: `tabularray` doesn't need `[table]` option. It doesn't depend on `colortbl` package.

Comment: @L.J.R., thank you very much!. This option is left from previous suggestion. I will delete it.

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix` (≥ 4.0) provides tools to color cells, rows and columns in a way compatible with `multirow` and `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c}[code-before = \rowcolor{teal!75}{2,3}]
 longer text\\
 \\
 \multirowcell{-2}[0ex][r]{shorter \\ short}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

You won't have the thin white lines you see in some PDF viewers at some levels of zoom (see for instance Bernard's answer).

[image: Result of above code]

Answer (score 0):

Makecell may have problems with  coloured cells in tables. As a workaround, I suggest to use `\Centerstack` from `stackengine` in a plain `\multirow`. Unrelated: loading `xcolor` with option `[table]`, you don't have to load `colortbl` since the former does it for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c}
  longer text\\
  \cellcolor{teal!75}\\
  \cellcolor{teal!75}\multirowcell{-2}[0ex][r]{shorter \\ short}
% \cellcolor{teal}\multirow{-2}*{short} % is ok but can't break line or set alignment
\end{tabular}
\qquad
\begin{tabular}{c}
  longer text\\
  \cellcolor{teal!75}\\
  \cellcolor{teal!75}\multirow{-2}{*}{\Centerstack[r]{shorter \\ short}}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `stackengine` have some trouble with `ehhline` package (or I use it in a wrong way), thank you anyway

Comment: Could you give  an example code of your problem(s)?

Comment: I did not record it in detail, so I forgot why I use `stackengine`, all I remember is that I just forgot to remove this package, then there is a strange problem and when I remove it, everything gets normal. But I will try to reproduce it when I finish my work. Since only loading the package will cause the problem, I believe I will produce it. Then I will ask another question.

Comment: I've just tried loading `ehhline` with this code, and I had no error nor warning, whatever the loading order.

Comment: Not this code, I draw all the horizon line of the table by `leaders` and `boxes` with `\hhline{!{}}`, I will ask another question soon(in 24h)

Comment: Sorry for late, go to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/540700/201158

Answer (score 0):

### Solution by David

use a nested tabular

```
\newcommand{\minitab}[2][l]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\cellcolor{teal}\multirow{-2}*{\minitab[r]{short\\short}
```