# a bug with calc and ehhline together

Tags: calc, hhline

Days before, I was dealing with the problem of drawing horizontal lines between colored multirow cell with `\hhline`. I tried two method and took the second at last. But I found there is a bug in the first method if `calc` is loaded.

All things are in my example code. Comment the `calc` package, the vertical line (red and teal ones) below the third row will be shown normally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{ehhline}
% \usepackage{calc} % make method 1 not work

%% vertical line
% vertical colored line #1 color #2 width
\newcommand{\vsl}[2]{\color{#1}\vrule width #2}
% colored solid line pattern
% #1 color #2 width #3 height
\newcommand{\hsp}[3]{\hbox{\textcolor{#1}{\rule{#2}{#3}}}}
% #1 top fill #2 bottom fill
\newcommand{\leaderfill}[1]{%
  \xleaders\hbox{%
    \vbox{\baselineskip=0pt\lineskip=0pt#1}%
  }\hfill%
}
% #1 color #2 height
\newcommand{\sfill}[2]{%
  \leaderfill{\hsp{#1}{0.1pt}{#2}}%
}
%% vline settings
% #1 rule width #2 color
\newcommand{\setvline}[2]{%
  \global\setlength\arrayrulewidth{#2}\arrayrulecolor{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{
  !{\vsl{red}{5pt}}c
  !{\vsl{teal}{5pt}}p{0.5cm}
  !{\vsl{blue}{3pt}}
}
% row 1
  \cellcolor{gray}
  & \cellcolor{yellow}\\
\hhline{
  ~ % blank in merged cell
  !{\sfill{black}{3pt}}
}
% row 2
  \cellcolor{gray}
  & \cellcolor{yellow}\\
\hhline{
  !{\sfill{gray}{3pt}} % overlap the vertical line
  !{\sfill{black}{3pt}}
}
% row 3
  \cellcolor{gray} third row
  & \cellcolor{orange}\\
% first method: set arrayrulewidth and arraycolor
% not work with calc
\hhline{
  >{\setvline{red}{5pt}}|
  !{\sfill{gray}{3pt}}
  >{\setvline{teal}{5pt}}|
  !{\sfill{black}{3pt}}
}
% row 4
  \cellcolor{gray}\tikz[->, baseline=-.5ex] \draw (0, 0) -- (-1ex, 1ex);
%   load calc
  not load
  & \cellcolor{pink}\\
% second method: use box
\hhline{
  >{\vsl{red}{5pt}}
  !{\sfill{gray}{3pt}}
  >{\vsl{teal}{5pt}}
  !{\sfill{black}{3pt}}
}
% row 5
  \cellcolor{gray}\multirow{-5}*{}
  & \cellcolor{cyan}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I have checked that the version of the package is 4.01, the latest version. And make sure that pdflatex and xelatex will both reproduce the problem. By the way , I'm using texlive 2020.

Comment: I rechecked and in "row 3" only, if I load `stackengine`, the solid red vertical bar gets a smll gray finger on the left side.  Same for teal bar. Is this the essence of the cited issue?

Comment: The `stackengine` package loads the `calc` package, and it is `calc` that is causing the issue.  If you load `calc` instead of `stackengine`, you will see the same issue.  Thus, there seems to be an incompatibility with `calc`.

Comment: yes, sorry for the bad example, I just wonder why this will happen and report this issue. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Reworking (editing) your MWE and question title to substitute `calc` instead of `stackengine` will get a different set of eyes looking at the problem, since the use of `calc` is more widespread than that of `stackengine`.

Comment: I put a query over on the chat site, to try to draw more eyes here.

Comment: I am doing this

Comment: \global\setlength is wrong syntax. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/297189/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thans very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MWE can be simplified to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ehhline}

\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm} !{\color{yellow}\vrule width 5pt} p{0.5cm}}
  a & b \\
  \hhline{
    -
    >{\global\setlength\arrayrulewidth{5pt}\arrayrulecolor{yellow}}|
    >{\global\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.4pt}} -
  }
  c & d
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From question comments, it is `calc`, loaded by `stackengine`, that redefines `\setlength` and forbids the never-supported syntax `\global\setlength`.

To change a length globally, you can use

```
\global\deflength{<length>}{<glue expression>}
```

where `\deflength` is defined by `etoolbox` package.

Or, you can avoid the need to change `\arrayrulewidth` globally in `>{...}` by using the new `hhline` preamble `V[<color>]{<width>}` from [my previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/539627/79060).

Inside `\hhline`, `V[<color>]{<width>}` acts like `|` with specific color and width. A full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ehhline}

\usepackage{stackengine}

\usepackage{xpatch} % or etoolbox
\usepackage{xparse}

\makeatletter
% based on \vline from latex2e
\def\HHvline#1{\vrule\@width#1}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \@ifpackageloaded{colortbl}{
    % based on \ifx\@tempb|...\else part of \HH@loop from colortbl.sty
    \NewDocumentCommand{\HH@preamble@V}{ m o m }{%
      \if@tempswa
        \ifx\CT@drsc@\relax
          \HH@add{\hskip\doublerulesep}%
        \else
          \HH@add{{\CT@drsc@\vrule\@width\doublerulesep}}%
        \fi
      \fi
      \@tempswatrue
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\HH@add{{\CT@arc@{\HHvline{#3}}}}}
        {\HH@add{{\color{#2}\HHvline{#3}}}}%
      \HH@let V%
    }
    \xpatchcmd\HH@loop
      {\PackageWarning{hhline}}
      {%
        \ifx\@tempb V% V[<color>]{<width>}
          \let\next\HH@preamble@V
        \else
        \PackageWarning{hhline}%
      }
      {}{\fail}
  }{
    % based on \ifx\@tempb|...\else part of \HH@loop from hhline.sty
    \NewDocumentCommand{\HH@preamble@V}{ m o m }{%
      \if@tempswa\HH@add{\hskip\doublerulesep}\fi\@tempswatrue
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\HH@add{\@tempc{\HHvline{#3}}\@tempc}}
        {\HH@add{\@tempc{\color{#2}\HHvline{#3}}\@tempc}}%
      \HH@let V%
    }
    \xpatchcmd\HH@loop
      {\PackageWarning{hhline}}
      {%
        \ifx\@tempb V% V[<color>]{<width>}
          \let\next\HH@preamble@V
        \else
      }
      {}{\fail}
  }
  \xpatchcmd\HH@loop
    {\fi\fi\fi}
    {\fi\fi\fi\fi}
    {}{\fail}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5cm} !{\color{yellow}\vrule width 5pt} p{0.5cm}}
  a & b \\
  \hhline{- V[yellow]{5pt} >{\arrayrulecolor{yellow}}-}
  c & d
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```